# Django - what are the advantages of django forms usage?

Tags: django, django-forms

I've been learning Django the ast few days and I've come to the point where I don't want the default form features anymore (the way their displayed in templates, validities, error messages, etc). So I use the tools django gives me to customize all of that.
However, by doing that, I end up with a code longer than that I had before I even used forms!

Is there an advantage of using forms over not using them (and just handle the request.POST/GET, and stuff) in a complex project?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868300/when-to-use-django-forms-vs-manual-forms/16868358#16868358

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Biggest advantage that first comes to mind:

**Validators for Forms and for Fields**

The above consist of:

- rejecting faulty input (missing fields etc).
- automatically generating error messages and binding them to appropriate template objects
- re-populating other fields that contain good data (it's really bad when visitors have to re-enter their form just because they got one field wrong)

Of course, all that can be achieved "manually" from the View, but IMO Forms are way more elegant.

**Some other benefits**, for more complex cases:

- FormSets - for showing multiple Forms of the same type at once (i.e. for simultaneous editing of several object of the same class)
- Seamless usage of multiple Forms on one View (with prefixes)
- Possibility to re-use Widgets (your custom Widgets), or plug in any third party widgets
- For really complex Views with Forms: the awesome [django-extra-views](https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views)
- ModelForms (the list would not be complete without it)

**Last**, but should always be first, except that it probably never is (in my own exp, anyway):

- separating the logical layers of your project, and
- keeping the code clean, adhering to conventions and best practices.

Comment: If just for validators, they are worth it.